# Shaving hair off mole during the three weeks/sefira

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, three-weeks, shaving

In regards to shaving/haircutting prohibition during the three weeks and/or sefira does this include hair on a mole on the face?

Comment: Why might it not that you think to ask?

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps it's not regular "hair" the classical sense...more of a mum maybe?

Comment: I would say this should be permissible if the hair on the mole looks unsightly.

Answer (score 2):

Found this question posed on https://dinonline.org/2018/04/22/cutting-other-hair-during-sefira/

Here is the text

Essentially the minhag not to cut hair applies to all hair of the body and not only to facial hair. However it is permitted for a woman to tweeze unsightly hair such as from her eyebrows nose ears, as this is not considered taking a haircut. (In general for a man, it is not permitted even not during sefira because of lo tilbash).  A married woman may shave her legs if not shaving them will bother her husband.

Sources:

O:CH 551-12, Aruch Hashulchan ibid 31, Kovetz Halachos (Sefira) 10-1,2,  Hilchos Chag Bchag (Sefiras Haomer) 7-14 ftnt. 55, M:B 79, Y:D 182-1.

Additionally, R' Shlomo Zalman Zt"l in Halichos Shlomo Bein Hamitzarim perek 14 Halacha 9 says that eyebrows and eyelashes are not even called shaving at all. Perhaps these can be in the same category

Comment: Note this is about sefira. During the week of tisha bav the prohibition is not merely customary and stricter rules may apply

Comment: Good point. Although i don't think anyone makes a difference. Additionally, R' Shlomo Zalman Zt"l in Halichos Shlomo Bein Hamitzarim perek 14 Halacha 9 says that eyebrows and eyelashes are not even called shaving at all. Perhaps these can be in the same category.

Comment: Hi and welcome on MY! Consider adding this piece of information to your answer by [editing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/124090/edit) it!